# What is the degree of freedom of a t-statistic when computed by using multiple samples of the two types of experiments?

Tags: t-test, degrees-of-freedom, pooling

Let's say I have samples `1, 2, 3`, and `4`. Out of these, `1` and `2` are due to the **type-1** experiment and `3` and `4` are due to **type-2** experiment (e.g. 1 and 2 are the readings from patients treated with **drug-1** and 3 and 4 are the readings for patients treated with **drug-2**.

I have sample mean and variances for all the 4 samples. I wish to conduct a t-test to compare the effect of **drug-1** (`sample-1` and `sample-2`) against that of **drug-2**.

I can combine samples **`1` and `2`** as well as **`3` and `4`** and calculate the combined sample means and sample variances to compute the t-statistic.

My question is, for this statistic, what would be the degree of freedom?

Is it `((n1+n2-1) + (n3+n4-1))` or `((n1-1)+(n2-1)+(n3-1)+(n4-1))`?

Answer (score 0):

df for the 2 sample independent t-test with equal variances is ((n1+n2-1) + (n3+n4-1)).

df for the 2 sample independent 
 [t-test with unequal variances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Equal_or_unequal_sample_sizes,_unequal_variances)  is rather complicated.

Testing if the 2 samples have the equal variances is done with an  [F test.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test_of_equality_of_variances)

Comment: If I understand correctly, I would combine these independent samples as 1+2 and 3+4 (two combined means and two combined pooled variances) and then the t-statistic will have ((n1+n2-1) + (n3+n4-1)) degrees of freedom?